# testing whether a Numpy array contains a given row

Tags: python, numpy

Is there a Pythonic and efficient way to check whether a Numpy array contains at least one instance of a given row?  By "efficient" I mean it terminates upon finding the first matching row rather than iterating over the entire array even if a result has already been found.

With Python arrays this can be accomplished very cleanly with `if row in array:`, but this does not work as I would expect for Numpy arrays, as illustrated below.

With Python arrays:

```
>>> a = [[1,2],[10,20],[100,200]]
>>> [1,2] in a
True
>>> [1,20] in a
False
```

but Numpy arrays give different and rather odd-looking results. (The `__contains__` method of `ndarray` seems to be undocumented.)

```
>>> a = np.array([[1,2],[10,20],[100,200]])
>>> np.array([1,2]) in a
True
>>> np.array([1,20]) in a
True
>>> np.array([1,42]) in a
True
>>> np.array([42,1]) in a
False
```

Comment: You are wishing for the impossible. Numpy does currently not provide anything that will stop when finding the first one. However, if you do this more then a few times sort based approaches are much more efficient anyway. As to the behaviour of `__contains__` I would almost say it is a bug (i.e. it works fine for scalars, but arrays are a bit weird, though internally it is just tom10 said anyway)

Comment: @seberg are you sure that no solution exists? If so then that is the answer to my question, so please post it and if I'm convinced I will accept it. Also if you could explain what you mean by "sort based approaches" it would be helpful. My array is in fact sorted so that the most commonly searched-for rows tend to be near the top, if that's what you mean - but this is no use unless the query method stops once it finds a match.

Comment: @seberg if `__collect__` was doing what tom10 said then the last input line quoted in my question would return `True`, no?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Numpys `__contains__` [is, at the time of writing this, `(a == b).any()`](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/7bc5480/numpy/core/src/multiarray/sequence.c#L114-L130) which is arguably only correct if `b` is a scalar (it is a bit hairy, but I believe – works like this only in 1.7. or later – this would be the right general method `(a == b).all(np.arange(a.ndim - b.ndim, a.ndim)).any()`, which makes sense for all combinations of `a` and `b` dimensionality)...

EDIT: Just to be clear, this is *not* necessarily the expected result when broadcasting is involved. Also someone might argue that it should handle the items in `a` separately as `np.in1d` does. I am not sure there is one clear way it should work.

Now you want numpy to stop when it finds the first occurrence. This AFAIK does not exist at this time. It is difficult because numpy is based mostly on ufuncs, which do the same thing over the whole array.
Numpy does optimize these kind of reductions, but effectively that only works when the array being reduced is already a boolean array (i.e. `np.ones(10, dtype=bool).any()`).

Otherwise it would need a special function for `__contains__` which does not exist. That may seem odd, but you have to remember that numpy supports many data types and has a bigger machinery to select the correct ones and select the correct function to work on it. So in other words, the ufunc machinery cannot do it, and implementing `__contains__` or such specially is not actually that trivial because of data types.

You can of course write it in python, or since you probably know your data type, writing it yourself in Cython/C is very simple.

---

That said. Often it is much better anyway to use sorting based approach for these things. That is a little tedious as well as there is no such thing as `searchsorted` for a `lexsort`, but it works (you could also abuse `scipy.spatial.cKDTree` if you like). This assumes you want to compare along the last axis only:

```
# Unfortunatly you need to use structured arrays:
sorted = np.ascontiguousarray(a).view([('', a.dtype)] * a.shape[-1]).ravel()

# Actually at this point, you can also use np.in1d, if you already have many b
# then that is even better.

sorted.sort()

b_comp = np.ascontiguousarray(b).view(sorted.dtype)
ind = sorted.searchsorted(b_comp)

result = sorted[ind] == b_comp
```

This works also for an array `b`, and if you keep the sorted array around, is also much better if you do it for a single value (row) in `b` at a time, when `a` stays the same (otherwise I would just `np.in1d` after viewing it as a recarray). *Important:* you must do the `np.ascontiguousarray` for safety. It will typically do nothing, but if it does, it would be a big potential bug otherwise.

Comment: Thanks, this is helpful. I will wait a few days in case anyone knows of some special clever solution and will accept this answer if not. (Evidently I was just being a bit dense about what (a==b).any() would return.)

Comment: I got an IndexError when `ind == len(sorted)` . This happens if `b` is 'beyond' the `sorted` array; e.g. `b = [101,0]`.

Answer (score 69):

You can use .tolist()

```
>>> a = np.array([[1,2],[10,20],[100,200]])
>>> [1,2] in a.tolist()
True
>>> [1,20] in a.tolist()
False
>>> [1,20] in a.tolist()
False
>>> [1,42] in a.tolist()
False
>>> [42,1] in a.tolist()
False
```

Or use a view:

```
>>> any((a[:]==[1,2]).all(1))
True
>>> any((a[:]==[1,20]).all(1))
False
```

Or generate over the numpy list (potentially VERY SLOW):

```
any(([1,2] == x).all() for x in a)     # stops on first occurrence
```

Or use numpy logic functions:

```
any(np.equal(a,[1,2]).all(1))
```

If you time these:

```
import numpy as np
import time

n=300000
a=np.arange(n*3).reshape(n,3)
b=a.tolist()

t1,t2,t3=a[n//100][0],a[n//2][0],a[-10][0]

tests=[ ('early hit',[t1, t1+1, t1+2]),
        ('middle hit',[t2,t2+1,t2+2]),
        ('late hit', [t3,t3+1,t3+2]),
        ('miss',[0,2,0])]

fmt='\t{:20}{:.5f} seconds and is {}'     

for test, tgt in tests:
    print('\n{}: {} in {:,} elements:'.format(test,tgt,n))

    name='view'
    t1=time.time()
    result=(a[...]==tgt).all(1).any()
    t2=time.time()
    print(fmt.format(name,t2-t1,result))

    name='python list'
    t1=time.time()
    result = True if tgt in b else False
    t2=time.time()
    print(fmt.format(name,t2-t1,result))

    name='gen over numpy'
    t1=time.time()
    result=any((tgt == x).all() for x in a)
    t2=time.time()
    print(fmt.format(name,t2-t1,result))

    name='logic equal'
    t1=time.time()
    np.equal(a,tgt).all(1).any()
    t2=time.time()
    print(fmt.format(name,t2-t1,result))
```

You can see that **hit or miss, the numpy routines are the same speed to search the array**. The Python `in` operator is *potentially* a lot faster for an early hit, and the generator is just bad news if you have to go all the way through the array.

Here are the results for 300,000 x 3 element array:

```
early hit: [9000, 9001, 9002] in 300,000 elements:
    view                0.01002 seconds and is True
    python list         0.00305 seconds and is True
    gen over numpy      0.06470 seconds and is True
    logic equal         0.00909 seconds and is True

middle hit: [450000, 450001, 450002] in 300,000 elements:
    view                0.00915 seconds and is True
    python list         0.15458 seconds and is True
    gen over numpy      3.24386 seconds and is True
    logic equal         0.00937 seconds and is True

late hit: [899970, 899971, 899972] in 300,000 elements:
    view                0.00936 seconds and is True
    python list         0.30604 seconds and is True
    gen over numpy      6.47660 seconds and is True
    logic equal         0.00965 seconds and is True

miss: [0, 2, 0] in 300,000 elements:
    view                0.00936 seconds and is False
    python list         0.01287 seconds and is False
    gen over numpy      6.49190 seconds and is False
    logic equal         0.00965 seconds and is False
```

And for 3,000,000 x 3 array:

```
early hit: [90000, 90001, 90002] in 3,000,000 elements:
    view                0.10128 seconds and is True
    python list         0.02982 seconds and is True
    gen over numpy      0.66057 seconds and is True
    logic equal         0.09128 seconds and is True

middle hit: [4500000, 4500001, 4500002] in 3,000,000 elements:
    view                0.09331 seconds and is True
    python list         1.48180 seconds and is True
    gen over numpy      32.69874 seconds and is True
    logic equal         0.09438 seconds and is True

late hit: [8999970, 8999971, 8999972] in 3,000,000 elements:
    view                0.09868 seconds and is True
    python list         3.01236 seconds and is True
    gen over numpy      65.15087 seconds and is True
    logic equal         0.09591 seconds and is True

miss: [0, 2, 0] in 3,000,000 elements:
    view                0.09588 seconds and is False
    python list         0.12904 seconds and is False
    gen over numpy      64.46789 seconds and is False
    logic equal         0.09671 seconds and is False
```

Which seems to indicate that `np.equal` is the fastest pure numpy way to do this...

Comment: Thanks, but I was looking for an implementation that will terminate after finding the first matching row, rather than iterating over the whole array as `tolist` does. The first version of the question was unclear about this; I've edited it.

Comment: Does the view method evaluate lazily? I suspect that calling .all on the view will create a whole new array, but I don't know how to find out.

Comment: A few points: 1) In "view", instead of a[:], I think you should use a[...]; 2) in "logic", I think you should use np.any and np.all instead of the python ones; 3) It would also be good to do a comparison for the False result, since that will be dramatically different for some of these cases (especially "gen").  +1, though, for an actual efficiency measure.

Comment: @Pyson many thanks for the update. I can see that in my use case np.equal will probably be faster than using a Python list, even though it doesn't get the bonus for terminating early. This is very useful to know.

Comment: Timing results are better done with the `timeit` module: with the `time.time()` method, the results can be very inaccurate if the system runs another task in background (the reported time is too large).

Comment: What does `all(1)` do?

Comment: The view method first does an element-wise equality check, so when you compare e.g. a 3-element vector to a list of 10 3-elements vectors (shape (10, 3)), you will have a (10, 3)-shaped array of Booleans. `all(1)` means `all(axis=1)`, so it will check each row whether all elements are `True`. In this case the row matches the vector that we compared to the array initially, and the (10, 3) array of Booleans is reduced to a 10-element vector. The `any` then checks whether at least one of these elements is `True`, meaning the queried vector was found at least once.

Answer (score 9):

I think

```
equal([1,2], a).all(axis=1)   # also,  ([1,2]==a).all(axis=1)
# array([ True, False, False], dtype=bool)
```

will list the rows that match.  As Jamie points out, to know whether at least one such row exists, use `any`:

```
equal([1,2], a).all(axis=1).any()
# True
```

Aside: 
I suspect `in` (and `__contains__`) is just as above but using `any` instead of `all`.

Comment: +1 Nice! You'll have to wrap it all up in `np.any(...)` to get a single membership boolean value, though.

Comment: Thanks. But this will iterate through the entire array and allocate a new array in memory containing the all the results, and only then check to see if it is empty. An efficient implementation would stop and return True as soon as it finds the first matching row.

Comment: I've edited the question to clarify what I meant by "efficient".

Answer (score 4):

I've compared the suggested solutions with [perfplot](https://github.com/nschloe/perfplot) and found that, if you're looking for a 2-tuple in a long unsorted list,

```py
np.any(np.all(a == b, axis=1))
```

is the fastest solution. An explicit short-circuit loop can always be faster if a match is found in the first few rows.

### [image]

Code to reproduce the plot:

```py
import numpy as np
import perfplot


target = [6, 23]


def setup(n):
    return np.random.randint(0, 100, (n, 2))


def any_all(data):
    return np.any(np.all(target == data, axis=1))


def tolist(data):
    return target in data.tolist()

def loop(data):
    for row in data:
        if np.all(row == target):
            return True
    return False


def searchsorted(a):
    s = np.ascontiguousarray(a).view([('', a.dtype)] * a.shape[-1]).ravel()
    s.sort()
    t = np.ascontiguousarray(target).view(s.dtype)
    ind = s.searchsorted(t)
    return (s[ind] == t)[0]


perfplot.save(
    "out02.png",
    setup=setup,
    kernels=[any_all, tolist, loop, searchsorted],
    n_range=[2 ** k for k in range(2, 20)],
    xlabel="len(array)",
)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to stop at the first occurrence, you could write a loop, like:

```
import numpy as np

needle = np.array([10, 20])
haystack = np.array([[1,2],[10,20],[100,200]])
found = False
for row in haystack:
    if np.all(row == needle):
        found = True
        break
print("Found: ", found)
```

However, I strongly suspect, that it will be much slower than the other suggestions which use numpy routines to do it for the whole array.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I was trying to avoid. It will be disappointing if it turns out that Numpy doesn't supply a built-in way of doing this.

Comment: Honestly, if you know that it is typically at the begging of the array, it is not a bad solution (and if `needle` is a large enough array, it is a good solution in any case).

Comment: Instead of using boolean flags, `any(np.all(row == needle) for row in haystack)` seems more Pythonic. This [still short circuits](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16505590/6243352).

Answer (score 0):

A much easier way to know whether a particular 1-D numpy array (row) exists or not in a 2-D numpy array is to use the following condition.

```
if np.sum(np.prod(2-darray == 1-darray),axis = 1)) > 0
```

If `np.sum(np.prod(2-darray == 1-darray),axis = 1))` is greater than `0` then the row exists in the 2-D array otherwise not.