# Numpy: How to check for tuples existence in ndarray

Tags: python, numpy, comparison

I found a strange behavior when working with tuples in numpy arrays. I want to get a table of booleans telling me which tuples in array `a` also exist in array `b`. Normally, I would use any of `in`, `in1d`. None of them work while `tuple(a[1]) == b[1,1]` yields `True`.

I fill my `a` and `b` like this:

```
a = numpy.array([(0,0)(1,1)(2,2)], dtype=tuple)

b = numpy.zeros((3,3), dtype=tuple)
for i in range(0,3):
    for j in range(0,3):
        b[i,j] = (i,j)
```

Can anyone tell me a solution to my problem and please enlighten me why this does not work as expected?

(Using python2.7 and numpy1.6.2 over here btw.)

Comment: This is almost: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14766194/testing-whether-a-numpy-array-contains-a-given-row/14772313 I think you may find an answer there.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Why this doesn't work**

The short version is that numpy's implementation of `array.__contains__()` seems to be broken. The `in` operator in python calls `__contains__()` behind the scenes.

Meaning that `a in b` is equivalent to `b.__contains__(a)`.

I've loaded up your arrays in a REPL and try the following:

```
>>> b[:,0]
array([(0, 0), (1, 0), (2, 0)], dtype=object)
>>> (0,0) in b[:,0] # we expect it to be true
False
>>> (0,0) in list(b[:,0]) # this shouldn't be different from the above but it is
True
>>>
```

**How to fix it**

I don't see how your list comprehension could work since `a[x]` is a tuple and `b[:,:]` is a 2D matrix so of course they're not equal. But I'm assuming you meant to use `in` instead of `==`. Do correct me if I'm wrong here and you meant something different that I'm just not seeing.

The first step is to convert `b` from a 2D array to a 1D array so we can sift through it linearly and convert it to a list to avoid numpy's broken `array.__contains()` like so:

```
bb = list(b.reshape(b.size))
```

Or, better yet, make it a `set` since tuples are immutable and checking for `in` in a set is O(1) instead of the list's O(n) behavior

```
>>> bb = set(b.reshape(b.size))
>>> print bb
set([(0, 1), (1, 2), (0, 0), (2, 1), (1, 1), (2, 0), (2, 2), (1, 0), (0, 2)])
>>>
```

Next we simply use the list comprehension to derive the table of booleans

```
>>> truth_table = [tuple(aa) in bb for aa in a]
>>> print truth_table
[True, True, True]
>>>
```

Full code:

```
def contained(a,b):
    bb = set(b.flatten())
    return [tuple(aa) in bb for aa in a]
```

Comment: Good to know that it's brokenness is a matter of fact.. I ended up using more or less the `Full code` example provided by this answers. Thanks a ton! One more question: Why did you pick `reshape` over `flatten`?

Comment: Because I've only used numpy very little and that's the first thing I found searching through `help(numpy.array)` :P I'm not sure the brokenness is a matter of fact but it does seem that way especially with the link in seberg's comment on your question. I'll amend the answer to use `flatten`

Comment: Even another question: Why does `x, y = zip(*a)` and `s = set(zip(x,y))` work while normally lists are mutable and therefore not directly transferable into sets?

Comment: Lists can be made into sets if they only contain non mutable objects. So you can't add a list to a set, but you van call `set(range(30))` for example. Since zip produces a list of tuples, you should be able to make that result into a set. That is of course if the tuples themselves don't contain anything mutable