# How does this input work with the Python 'any' function?

Tags: python, generator-expression

In the python docs page for [`any`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#any), the equivalent code for the `any()` function is given as:

```
def any(iterable):
    for element in iterable:
        if element:
            return True
    return False
```

How does this function know what element I wanna test if call it in this form?

```
any(x > 0 for x in list)
```

From the function definition, all I can see is that I'm passing an iterable object. How does the `for` loop know I am looking for something `> 0`?

Comment: This question, as it turns out, wasn't actually about `any`, but about the *argument to* `any` in the example code, which is a *generator expression*. I thus closed it as a duplicate of the reference question for generator expressions. If you are actually looking for information about `any`, please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19389490 for the canonical.

Answer (score 189, accepted):

If you use `any(lst)` you see that `lst` is the iterable, which is a list of some items. If it contained `[0, False, '', 0.0, [], {}, None]` (which all have boolean values of `False`) then `any(lst)` would be `False`. If `lst` also contained any of the following `[-1, True, "X", 0.00001]` (all of which evaluate to `True`) then `any(lst)` would be `True`.

In the code you posted, `x > 0 for x in lst`, this is a different kind of iterable, called a **generator expression**. Before generator expressions were added to Python, you would have created a **list comprehension**, which looks very similar, but with surrounding `[]`'s: `[x > 0 for x in lst]`. From the `lst` containing `[-1, -2, 10, -4, 20]`, you would get this *comprehended list*: `[False, False, True, False, True]`. This internal value would then get passed to the `any` function, which would return `True`, since there is at least one `True` value.

But with **generator expressions**, Python no longer has to create that internal list of `True(s)` and `False(s)`, the values will be generated as the `any` function iterates through the values generated one at a time by the generator expression. *And*, since `any` short-circuits, it will stop iterating as soon as it sees the first `True` value. This would be especially handy if you created `lst` using something like `lst = range(-1,int(1e9))` (or `xrange` if you are using *Python2.x*). Even though this expression will generate over a billion entries, `any` only has to go as far as the third entry when it gets to `1`, which evaluates `True` for `x>0`, and so `any` can return `True`.

If you had created a **list comprehension**, Python would first have had to create the billion-element list in memory, and then pass that to `any`. But by using a **generator expression**, you can have Python's builtin functions like `any` and `all` break out early, as soon as a `True` or `False` value is seen.

Comment: It would be also worth mentioning that `any(x > 0 for x in list)` is just a syntactic sugar for `any((x > 0 for x in list))`.

Comment: You ought to add `None` to the list of elements which have boolean values of `False`

Comment: Adding to @georg, the syntactic sugar is not special to `any`. `def b(x): return x; print b(x > 1 for x in xs) # prints <generator object ..`

Comment: @georg Thank you for this clarification. This is a really important point that had me confused when testing the code with any brackets.

Comment: `not set()` also seems to evaluate to `True` so I would also add that to the list. Actually this is not a comprehensive list, but pointless to add it here, better link to it - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43692516/what-are-the-true-and-false-criteria-for-a-python-object

Answer (score 50):

```
>>> names = ['King', 'Queen', 'Joker']
>>> any(n in 'King and john' for n in names)
True

>>> all(n in 'King and Queen' for n in names)
False
```

It just reduce several line of code into one.
You don't have to write lengthy code like:

```
for n in names:
    if n in 'King and john':
       print True
    else:
       print False
```

Answer (score 23):

`(x > 0 for x in list)` in that function call creates a generator expression eg.

```
>>> nums = [1, 2, -1, 9, -5]
>>> genexp = (x > 0 for x in nums)
>>> for x in genexp:
        print x


True
True
False
True
False
```

Which `any` uses, and shortcircuits on encountering the first object that evaluates `True`

Answer (score 9):

It's because the iterable is

```
(x > 0 for x in list)
```

Note that `x > 0` returns either `True` or `False` and thus you have an iterable of booleans.

Answer (score 7):

Simply saying, any() does this work : according to the condition even if it encounters one fulfilling value in the list, it returns true, else it returns false.

```
list = [2,-3,-4,5,6]

a = any(x>0 for x in lst)

print a:
True


list = [2,3,4,5,6,7]

a = any(x<0 for x in lst)

print a:
False
```