# Why doesn't this Python "any" function return True?

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, any

I don't understand why any() is not working the way I expect it to.  Below, I want to say, if any of the cities in the cities list are in the phrase.split(), return True.  But why does it return false when phrase.split() is `['replacement', 'windows', 'in', 'seattle', 'wa']` and 'seattle' is clearly in the phrase.split() list?

```
>>> cities = ['seattle', 'san antonio', 'denver']
>>> phrase = 'replacement windows in seattle wa'
>>> any(cities) in phrase.split()
False
>>> 'seattle' in phrase.split()
True
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How exactly does the python any() function work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16505456/how-exactly-does-the-python-any-function-work)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Becuse `any(cities)` return True, and True is not in the list:

```
>>> cities = ['seattle', 'san antonio', 'denver']
>>> phrase = 'replacement windows in seattle wa'
>>> any(cities)
True
>>> True in phrase.split()
False
>>> any(cities) in phrase.split()
False
```

You can use this way to see if any city in the list:

```
>>> [i for i in cities if i in phrase.split()]
['seattle']
>>> any(i for i in phrase.split() if i in cities)
True
```

Comment: @zoosuck Thank you, this is very helpful in helping me understand why any() was returning False.

Comment: Your `any` is backwards -- should be `any(i in cities for i in phrase.split())`

Comment: You did not change it. You just change a list comprehension into a generator...  Compare `any((i for i in phrase.split() if i in cities))` to `any(i in cities for i in phrase.split())` in the first form, phrase is being split repeatedly

Answer (score 3):

Because in `any(cities)` will return `True` for a non-empty list, or `False` for an empty list - that value is never contained in your membership test. Also note that splitting by space is going to separate `san antonio` into two words, so using this approach you won't be able to match it. An alternative is instead to use a regular expression:

```
import re

cities = ['seattle', 'san antonio', 'denver']
phrase = 'replacement windows in seattle wa'

has_city = re.compile('|'.join(sorted(cities, key=len, reverse=True))).search
if has_city(phrase):
    # do whatever
```

This is very similar to `if any(city in phrase for city in cities)` (it will find san antonio) but requires multiple parses over `phrase` instead of the regex doing it just once.

You might also wish to consider `re.escaping` the strings and applying word boundaries depending on the exact criteria for matching.

Comment: Thank you very much for your well thought-out response.  I would have never thought of your suggestion.  I also was wondering about how to handle multi-word cities since `split()` spits on spaces so thanks for helping me on this aspect as well.

Answer (score 1):

Try this statement

```
any(word in phrase.split() for word in cities)
```

Your original statement is not really testing every word in "cities" to every word in "phrase.split()."

Answer (score 0):

```
any(x for x in cities if x in phrase.split())
```

Answer (score 0):

Here goes another way to do it correctly,

```
any(word in cities for word in phrase.split())
```

Or,

```
any(True for word in phrase.split() if word in cities)
```