# Scanning a list for words in dictionary - python

Tags: python

I have been asked at school to explain what the following line of code means.

```
if any(word in 'variable' for word in list_):
```

I know what it does but I am having trouble putting it into words. If anyone could give me an explanation I would really appreciate it.

I have found other explanations, however these are too advanced for what I am doing in school. I need the explanation to be simple but it also needs to be detailed at the same time.

My explanation is: 
for word in list_ searches for each Word in the list and gives it  a name, word. For each word we see if word is in the string 'variable'. any() will tell us if one of the words matches.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How exactly does the python any() function work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16505456/how-exactly-does-the-python-any-function-work)

Comment: Can you show us your attempt to put it into words? Then we can see if you understood it correctly.

Comment: Please, explain what you are thinking so that it shows you have done at least some efforts!

Comment: `for word in list_ searches for each Word in the list ` - it rather iterates or loops, not searches. `any() will tell us if one of the words matches.` - if **at least** one is important here. Otherwise it's pretty good explanation! :)