# What are the true and false criteria for a python object?

Tags: python, python-3.x, truthiness

I have seen the following cases:

```
>>> def func(a):
...     if a:
...         print("True")
...
>>> a = [1, 2, 3]
>>> func(a)
True
>>> a == True
False
```

Why does this difference occur?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

All objects<sup>1</sup> in Python have a [truth value](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing):

> Any object can be tested for truth value, for use in an `if` or `while` condition or as operand of the Boolean operations below. The following values are considered false:
>
> - `None`
> - `False`
> - zero of any numeric type, for example, `0`, `0.0`, `0j`.
> - any empty sequence, for example, `''`, `()`, `[]`.
> - any empty mapping, for example, `{}`.
> - instances of user-defined classes, if the class defines a `__bool__()` or `__len__()` method, when that method returns the integer zero or bool value `False`.
>
> All other values are considered true — so objects of many types are always true.

---

<sup>1</sup> … unless they have a `__bool__()` method which raises an exception, or returns a value other than `True` or `False`. The former is unusual, but sometimes reasonable behaviour (for example, see the comment by user2357112 below); the latter is not.

Comment: Well, usually, anyway. This is one of the parts where the docs gloss over the more subtle aspects of operator overloading. You can make a class where trying to take its truth value throws a TypeError, and this is sometimes reasonable, such as for NumPy arrays.

Answer (score 2):

When you type `if a:`, it is equivalent to `if bool(a):`. So it doesn't mean that `a is True`, only that `a`'s representation as a boolean value is `True`.

Generally speaking `bool` is a subclass of `int`, where `True == 1` and `False == 0`.