# Python, which magic method is invoked for "if object" statement

Tags: python

I have a question that I couldn't find answere also during my testing.
Methods **pos** and **neg** doesn't work for me.

Let suppose we have a simple class:

```
class Test:
def __init__(self,
             param=False):
    self.param = param

if __name__ == '__main__':
    c = Test()
    if c:  # which Python magic method is invoked here?
        print("OK")
    else:
        print("Nok")
```

And now, I want to override magic method which is invoked when I make statement:

> if c:

But I don't know which? Please for advice.

Comment: check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43692516/what-are-the-true-and-false-criteria-for-a-python-object

Comment: Thank you, excatly it is similar question.

Answer (score 8):

`__bool__()` if its defined
see https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html

By default an object resolves to `True`