# Why line is executed even when condition is false?

Tags: python-3.x, if-statement, pycharm, conditional-statements

I have a function that receives a string argument and condition inside this function that checks if this argument is int or float. Although the outcome of this condition is false, the following line is still executed.

I use PyCharm IDE and Python 3.8

Here is the code.

```
number1 = 17
number2 = 17.1
testStr = "Test string"


def define_type(argument01):
    if type(argument01) == str:
        print(argument01 + " - string")
    if type(argument01) == int or float:
        print(str(argument01) + " - int or float")


define_type(testStr)
```

The output:

```
Test string - string
Test string - int or float

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> if type(argument01) == int or float:
> ```

can be rewritten

```
if (type(argument01) == int) or float:
```

so even *argument01* is not an *int* the test is always true, in a way your test is

```
if float:
```

You want :

```
if type(argument01) == int or type(argument01) == float:
```

Comment: It works! Thank you. But why "if float:" is a valid conditional? It doesn't mean anything. Does it?

Comment: @Seeker001 yes, and because *float* is not *false* then it is true. An empty string is considered false, a non empty is considered true, same for set and array, etc. Python is very practical and follow 'common sense'

Comment: @Seeker001 Hope this helps: [What are the true and false criteria for a python object?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43692661/1589191)

Comment: @EmilMGeorge for sure it is a good link