# Delete list word combination python 3

Tags: python, arrays, list, for-loop

I have a list of strings that i would like to search for a word combination.
Then delete the list if the combination is not there. Is there a python list 
comprehension that would work?

```
word_list = ["Dogs love ice cream", "Cats love balls", "Ice cream", "ice cream is good with pizza", "cats hate ice cream"]

keep_words = ["Dogs", "Cats"] 

Delete_word = ["ice cream"]
```

Delete words that have ice cream in it but if dogs or cats is in the sentence keep it.

```
Desired_output = ["Dogs love ice cream", "Cats love balls", "cats hate ice cream"]
```

Was trying this code also tried AND and OR but cannot get the combination right.

```
output_list = [x for x in  word_list if "ice cream" not in x]
```

Comment: do `ice cream` needs to be together? Like will this sentence be considered valid:`keep cream over the ice`?

Comment: I was thinking of it together "ice cream" but very good point

Comment: The last one is contain `cat` not `cats`!

Comment: good spot Kasramvd cats i will edit

Answer (score 7):

Here's a list comprehension solution:

```
[x for x in word_list if any(kw.lower() in x.lower() for kw in keep_words) 
 or all(dw.lower() not in x.lower() for dw in Delete_word)]
# ['Dogs love ice cream', 'Cats love balls', 'cats hate ice cream']
```

This also adds flexibility for multiple words in the delete words list.

**Explanation**

Iterate over the list and keep the word if either of the following are `True`:

- Any of the keep words are in x
- None of the delete words are in x

I presume from your example that you wanted this to be case insensitive, so make all comparison on the lower-cased versions of the words.

Two helpful functions are [`any()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16505456/how-exactly-does-the-python-any-function-work/16505590) and [`all()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19389490/how-do-pythons-any-and-all-functions-work).

Comment: Pault very interesting i didn't think about "any and all" --- Thank you so much for the help

Answer (score 5):

As an optimized approach you can put your `keep_word` and `delete_words` within set and use `itertools.filterfalse()` to filter the list out:

```
In [48]: def key(x):
             words = x.lower().split()
             return keep_words.isdisjoint(words) or not delete_words.isdisjoint(words)
   ....: 

In [49]: keep_words = {"dogs", "cats"}

In [51]: delete_words = {"ice cream"}

In [52]: list(filterfalse(key ,word_list))
Out[52]: ['Dogs love ice cream', 'Cats love balls', 'cats hate ice cream']
```

Comment: Kasramvd a very very very interesting technique l like it - thank you for the help

Comment: `return keep_words.isdisjoint(words) or Delete_word.intersection(words)` could be improved _not_ to generate the intersection like this: `return keep_words.isdisjoint(words) or not Delete_word.is_disjoint(words)`

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre That's even better!

Comment: also `x.lower()` can be replaced by `x.casefold()` so german "beta" is lowered as double "s". more powerful than a single `str.lower`

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> list(filter(lambda x: not any(i in x for i in Delete_word)
...                       or  any(i in x for i in keep_words), word_list))
['Dogs love ice cream', 'Cats love balls', 'Ice cream']
```

Modify this accordingly for a case-insensitive implementation.