# Using return statements in Python loops

Tags: python, loops

```
def has_a_vowel(a_str):
    for letter in a_str:
        if letter in "aeiou":
            return True
        else:
            return False
    print("Done!")
```

Calling this function would only check the first element... How can I get it to run through the string before returning True or False?
Thank you

Answer (score 4):

It would be esiest to remove the `else: return False` and `return False` outside the loop:

```
def has_a_vowel(a_str):
    for letter in a_str:
        if letter in "aeiou":
            return True    # this leaves the function

    print("Done!")     # this prints only if no aeiou is in the string
    return False       # this leaves the function only after the full string was checked
```

or simpler:

```
def has_a_vowel(a_str): 
    return any(x in "aeiou" for x in a_str)
```

(which would not print Done though).

Readup:

- [How exactly does the python any() function work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16505456/how-exactly-does-the-python-any-function-work)
- [any()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any)