# Using tuples of bools for if statements

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement, tuples

I would like to know if it is a good practice to use tuples instead of separated expressions in a if statement.

```
is_dog = True
is_brown = False
```

I would like to do like this:

```
if (is_dog, is_brown):
    do_something()
```

Instead of like this:

```
if is_dog or is_brown:
    do_something()
```

What is the best practice in this case?
**Thank you**

Comment: I don't understand, even both `is_dog` and `is_cat` is True, `if (is_cat, is_dog):` will be True`if (is_cat, is_dog):` not equals to `if is_dog or is_cat:`

Comment: You want to take a look at `any` and `all`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19389490/how-do-pythons-any-and-all-functions-work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is *not* good practice to see if either bool is `True`:

```
if (False,False):
    print("it does not do what you think it does")
```

Output:

```
it does not do what you think it does
```

See [python truth value testing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing): any *non empty* tuple is `True`-thy

The correct way is:

```
if a or b:   
    pass
```

For multiples you can use [`any()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16505456/how-exactly-does-the-python-any-function-work):

```
if any(x for x in (False, True)):
    pass   # will enter here if any part of the tuple is True
else:
    pass   # will enter here if no part of the tuple is True
```

Answer (score 4):

There are a few things going on here:

You're using a tuple as the branching value for `if`. The truthiness of a predicate only indicates if its empty or not, and nothing about its contents:

```
assert bool(tuple()) is False
assert bool((False, )) is True
```

Second, if you know in advance the number of items in the tuple, using `or`s and `and`s is usually more readable, like you mentioned:

```
if is_dog or is_cat:
    do_something()
```

And lastly, you can use `any` for arbitrary number of values:

```
values = [is_dog, is_cat, ... more]
if any(values):
    do_something()
```