# I don't fully understand how the any() function in this script works

Tags: python, python-3.x, any

I have a script that checks if there are one or more of the same items in a list. Here's the code:

```
items = ["Blue", "Black", "Red"]

def isUnique(item):
    seen = list()
    return not any(i in seen or seen.append(i) for i in item)


print(isUnique(items))
```

It prints "True" if all the items in the given list are unique and "False" if one or more items in the list are unique. Can someone please explain the `any()` part of the script for me as I don't fully understand how it works?

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16505456/how-exactly-does-the-python-any-function-work/16505590

Comment: @rv.kvetch That explains how `any()` works in general, it doesn't explain the logic of this use.

Comment: the most glaring inefficiency here is the use of `list` instead of `set`: `i in seen` is `O[n]` if `seen` is a `list`, vs. `O[1]` if it is a `set`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This code is kind of a hack, since it uses a generator expression with side-effects and exploits the fact that `append` returns `None`, which is falsy.

The equivalent code written in the imperative style is like so:

```py
def isUnique(items):
    seen = list()
    for i in items:
        if i in seen or seen.append(i):
            return False
    return True
```

The `or` is still a bit strange there - it is being used for its [short-circuiting behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation), so that `append` is only called when `i in seen` is false - so we could rewrite it like this:

```py
def isUnique(items):
    seen = list()
    for i in items:
        if i in seen:
            return False
        else:
            seen.append(i)
    return True
```

This is equivalent because `append` is only called when `i in seen` is false, and the call to `append` returns `None` which means the `return False` line shouldn't execute in that case.

Comment: I've always found that explaining confusing code by showing equivalent code is best, so +1.

Comment: why not simply `len(items) == len(set(items))`?  This repeated checking for items in a list hurts my sensibility...

Comment: @PierreD Because that wouldn't explain the code which the OP asked for an explanation of. It is just a completely different solution to the same problem, so it would not answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

It is quite simple: the expression inside `any()` is a [generator](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289/). `any()` draws from that generator and returns `True` (and **stops**) at the first element from the generator that is `True`. If it exhausts the generator, then it returns `False`.

The expression in the generator (`i in seen or seen.append(i)`) is a trick to express as a one-liner the logic that: if `i` is in the list, the expression is `True` and `any()` stops immediately, otherwise, `i` is added to the list and the generator continues.

The function can be significantly improved by using a `set` instead of a `list`:

```py
def isUnique(item):
    seen = set()
    return not any(i in seen or seen.add(i) for i in item)
```

It is much faster to test for presence of an item in a `set` (`O[1]`) than in a `list` (`O[n]`).

One interesting and perhaps underappreciated aspect of this code is that it works on a (potentially infinite) generator. It will **stop** drawing from the generator at the first repeated item. Subsequent items that would be obtained by the generator are not evaluated at all (with potential side-effects, desirable or not).

A different approach, suitable for known and finite collections of items, would be the following:

```py
def isUnique(items):
    items = tuple(items)  # in case items is a generator
    return len(set(items)) == len(items)
```

This assumes that all the items fit in memory. Obviously this won't work if `items` is a generator of a very large or infinite number of elements.

Comment: Note that using a `set` only works if the items are hashable.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: there are great answers. Adding some simpler ways to achieve the wanted result:

Method 1:

```
items = ["Blue", "Black", "Red"]
items_set = set(items)
if len(items_set) != len(items):
    # there are duplications
```

This works because a set object ‘removes’ duplications.

Method 2:

```
contains_duplicates = any(items.count(element) > 1 for element in items) # true if contains duplications and false otherwise.
```

See https://www.kite.com/python/answers/how-to-check-for-duplicates-in-a-list-in-python
———————————————

`any` is a great function

> Return True if any element of the iterable is true. If the iterable is empty, return False

Your function `isUnique`, however, does a bit more logic. Let's break it down:

First you create an empty list object and store it in 'seen' variable.

`for i in item` - iterates the list of items.

`i in seen` - This statement returns True if 'i' is a member of 'seen', and false otherwise.

`seen.append(i)` - add i to seen. This statement returns None if 'i' is appeneded to seen successfully.

Notice the `or` statement between `i in seen or seen.append(i)`. That means, if one of the statements here is True, the or statement returns True.

At this point, I'd run `[i in seen or seen.append(i) for i in item]`, see the result and experiment with it. The result for your example is `[None, None, None]`.

Basically, for each item, you both add it to the list and check if it is already in the list.

Finally, you use the `any()` function - which returns True if the iterable has a `True` value. This will happen only if `i in seen` will return True.

Notice you are using `not any(...)`, which returns False in case there are no repititions.

There are simpler and clearer ways to implement this. You should try!

Answer (score 0):

Here you need to understand first how `or` operator works.
or is like `exp1 or exp2`

it just evaluates the expression which gives True first or give true at last

eg

```
>>> 2 or 3
2
>>> 5 or 0.0
5
>>> [] or 3
3
>>> 0 or {}
{}
```

now for your list comprehension, `[i in seen or seen.append(i) for i in items]`    `i in seen` evaluate false and `seen.append(i)` True and which return `None` ie `list.append` return None so , comprehension contain all None

```
>>> seen = []
>>> items = ["Blue", "Black", "Red"]
>>> res = [i in seen or seen.append(i) for i in items]
>>> res
[None, None, None]
>>> any(res)
False
```

as per `any` documentation, it is returning false beacuse as it is not getting iterable or bool.

```
>>> help(any)
Help on built-in function any in module builtins:

any(iterable, /)
    Return True if bool(x) is True for any x in the iterable.

    If the iterable is empty, return False.
```

Answer (score 0):

the `any` function in python takes a list of booleans and returns the OR of all of them.

the `i in seen or seen.append(i) for i in item` appends `i` to `seen` if it's not in `seen` already. but if it is already in seen then the append() does not run since the first part is already True, and python doesn't need to know if the second part is true since True OR'd with anything is True. so it doesn't execute it. so the `seen` array ends up being a unique list of colours it has seen.

`i in seen or seen.append(i) for i in item` is also a generator expression,
which generates booleans, and `any` checks the booleans it generates, if even one of them evaluates to True, the whole `any` will return True.

so the first time an item that is already in the `seen` array is found, any will stop the generator and return True itself.

so if a duplicate element happens to be in the array no more conditions are evaluated and no more elements are appended to `seen` array

so if the array had duplicate elements, like,

```
items = ["Blue", "Blue", "Black", "Red"]


def isUnique(item):
    seen = list()
    unique = not any(i in seen or seen.append(i) for i in item)
    print(seen)
    return unique


isUnique(items)
```

would result in the output, just
`['Blue']`