# check if a numpy 1d sub-array is consecutively included in a numpy Nd array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Defined a 1d array (or a 1d slice of a bigger array), like:

```
a=np.array([ 5, 12, 13])
```

if there some higher dimension array, like:

```
c1=np.array([[1, 2, 3], [ 5, 12, 13], [7, 8, 9]])
c2=np.array([[1, 2, 3], [ 5, 6, 7], [7, 8, 9]])
```

It turns out to be:

```
a in c1, a in c2
(True, True)
```

I would like that only the first condition, where `a` is consecutively contained as sub-array to be `True`. While `a in c2` would give `False`. 
Is there any function taking care of that?

Comment: Isn't the first `True` not just accidentally true? If you change a to `a=np.array([ 5, 12, 13])` the output is `(True, False)` and should be `(False, False)`.

Comment: mmmh ... I just edit the formatting in case it was misleading (some extra space). However I don't get your point @andi.

Comment: Your code returns true when only one element of a is found in c1 or c2. But I think you want to check if the entire array is found in c1 or c2. Am I wrong?

Comment: Expected output for `a in c1.T` ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [testing whether a Numpy array contains a given row](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14766194/2379410)

Comment: @andi: exactly, I want to check if the entire array `a` is present as an "element" contained in the array-of-array. It is indeed more or less what was already posted, thanks @moarningsun.

Answer (score 2):

I think, this is what you want:

```
import numpy as np

a=np.array([ 5, 12, 13])

c1=np.array([[1, 2, 3], [5,12,13], [7, 8, 9]])
c2=np.array([[1, 2, 3], [5,6,7], [7, 8, 9]])

print any((a == x).all() for x in c1)
print any((a == x).all() for x in c2)
```

It outputs:

```
True
False
```

**Edit:** as moarningsun suggested, here a better version:

```
import numpy as np

a=np.array([ 5, 12, 13])

c1=np.array([[1, 2, 3], [5,12,13], [7, 8, 9]])
c2=np.array([[1, 2, 3], [5,6,7], [7, 8, 9]])

print np.any((a == c1).all(axis=1))
print np.any((a == c2).all(axis=1))
```

Comment: Although this will return true if the sub-array being searched for 'wraps' around to the next row.

Comment: Is this not what he wanted?

Comment: `np.all` takes an "axis" parameter, which is more efficient than the generator expression you have now

Comment: Sorry, I was not aware of this. Would you mind editing the answer? I would also be very interested.

Comment: It's just `np.any((a == c1).all(axis=1))`. It "broadcasts" `a` to the shape of `c1`.

Comment: @  moarningsun: If I modify code acordingly, I get not the desired output, but rather twice "<generator object <genexpr> at 0x0000000009476090>"

Comment: Oh but you don't need to modify the code, you can just paste my code "as is" in your interpreter and you'll see the desired output `:)`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54965/discussion-between-moarningsun-and-andi).

Comment: in the EDIT by @moarningsun there is a mispelled "import" at the beginning of each line, if someone can remove it, thanks.

Comment: I confirm that the edit is necessary, because I am looking for the exact occurence of that subarray (as a row in this case) into the 2d one. PS: there is still one "a" to remove in the beginning of the line.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `.tolist()` and then call the functions normally:

```
>>> a=np.array([ 5, 12, 13])
>>> c1=np.array([[1, 2, 3], [ 5, 12, 13], [7, 8, 9]])
>>> c2=np.array([[1, 2, 3], [ 5, 6, 7], [7, 8, 9]])
>>> a.tolist() in c1.tolist(), a.tolist() in c2.tolist()
(True, False)
>>>
```