# True returned in both cases, when it contains an element and when not. Why?

Tags: python, multidimensional-array

Let's say I've created an integer 2d array:

```
import numpy as np
ar1 = np.random.randint(10, size=(4,2))
v1 = ar1[0]
v2 = [4,4]
ar1 = np.array([[5, 7],
                [7, 5],
                [9, 2],
                [0, 1]])
```

I want to check if v1 and v2 are elements of ar1. By 'elements' I mean 'rows':

```
v1 in ar1
v2 in ar1
```

And I get `True` in both cases. What am I doing wrong? Is there a better way to check if the vector matches a row of the array? Looping through rows (i.e. `for rows in ar1:`) is not an option.

EDIT: another way is to sum matching values in every row and check if the sum is 2, but it's lame and unpythonic

Comment: Did you paste your code correctly? What is `ar2`?

Comment: ar2 is not defined here, so for all we know, v2 is actually in ar2

Comment: *"looping through rows... is not an option"* what do you think the `in` operation does in the case of an unstructured array/list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `np.any` with `np.all` with conditionals.  The *row* you are checking for must be [broadcastable](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/ufuncs.html#broadcasting) - [Array Broadcasting in numpy](https://github.com/dwf/rescued-scipy-wiki/blob/master/EricsBroadcastingDoc.rst#array-broadcasting-in-numpy).

```
import numpy as np
v1 = np.array([9,2])
v2 = np.array([2,9])
v3 = np.array([9,4])
ar1 = np.array([[5, 7],
                [7, 5],
                [9, 2],
                [0, 1]])

>>> ar1 == v1
array([[False, False],
       [False, False],
       [ True,  True],
       [False, False]], dtype=bool)
>>> ar1 == v2
array([[False, False],
       [False, False],
       [False, False],
       [False, False]], dtype=bool)
>>> ar1 == v3
array([[False, False],
       [False, False],
       [ True, False],
       [False, False]], dtype=bool)
>>> np.any(np.all(ar1 == v1 , axis = 1)), np.any(np.all(ar1 == v2, axis = 1)), np.any(np.all(ar1 == v3, axis = 1))
(True, False, False)
>>>
```

Comment: Neat, this works well

Comment: @Alex, Do you understand how it works - so you can adapt it?

Comment: in fact the absolutely best way is to use set(): then you can use a in b (set), and it does exactly what I want

Comment: @Alex if you think that is the best solution,you could post it as an answer with examples - it's OK to answer your own question.

Answer (score 1):

If they were lists instead of numpy arrays, this would work.

```
ar1 = np.array([[5, 7],
                [7, 5],
                [9, 2],
                [0, 1]])

[7, 5] in ar1 ## True
[7, 6] in ar1 ## True

[7, 5] in ar1.tolist() ## True
[7, 6] in ar1.tolist() ## False
```

Comment: @Shashank if your statement is true, can you explain the result I get then?

Comment: I'd be happy to remove my answer but I'd love an explanation

Comment: See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14766194/testing-whether-a-numpy-array-contains-a-given-row . Basically, numpy's `in` does *not* do what you expect it to do for non-single-element searches.

Comment: Ok, thanks @aruisdante but the solution still seems valid (it is also suggested in the most popular answer on the post you linked to)

Comment: @JulienSpronck Yes, but `tolist()` is likely *O(n)*, and then you still have to perform another *O(n)* search for the `in` operator. At that point might as well just do a `for` on the original input matrix and save an iteration over the data..

Comment: right, that's true ... probably not the fastest. Thanks again, @aruisdante

Comment: @JulienSpronck However, both `tolist()` and `in` (for `list`) are implemented in C, so it's possible that even though it requires two iterations over the data, it still winds up being faster for many real datasets. You'd have to benchmark to find out for sure.

Comment: @aruisdante ... for all I know, the data was converted from a list to a numpy array in the first place :-)