# Test if a list is present in a numpy ndarray?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I want to know if a list [a, b] is present in numpy ndarray.

**I tried this :**

```
list1 = np.array([[1, 2], [1, 3], [2, 4]])

[1, 5] in list1
```

**The result is :**

```
True
```

It seems that it only the presence of the first number is checked, leading to a false response.

What is the good way to check if the list is present or not ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [testing whether a Numpy array contains a given row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14766194/testing-whether-a-numpy-array-contains-a-given-row)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple way is to use `tolist()`.

```
>>> list1 = np.array([[1, 2], [1, 3], [2, 4]])
>>> [1, 2] in list1.tolist()
True
>>> [1, 5] in list1.tolist()
False
```

Answer (score 3):

This is one way:

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.array([[1, 2], [1, 3], [2, 4]])

lst = np.array([1, 5])
any((lst==i).all() for i in arr)  # False

lst = np.array([1, 2])
any((lst==i).all() for i in arr)  # True
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It works well. Why did you convert the second list (lst) to a np array ?

Comment: @Mairkur, you should compare similar types, e.g. list to list or np.array to np.array. The conversion ensures this happens.