# How do I check if np.array exist inside another np.array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I need to find if the np.array exists in another np.array. I have a np.array that is `doubles = [[ 0  3][ 0 11][ 1  1][ 1 13][ 2  2][ 2  6][ 2  8][ 2 12][ 3  0][ 3  3][ 3  7][ 3 11][ 3 14][ 4  4][ 4 10][ 6  2][ 6  6][ 6  8][ 6 12][ 7  3][ 7  7][ 7 11][ 8  2][ 8  6][ 8  8][ 8 12][10  4][10 10][11  0][11  3][11  7][11 11][11 14][12  2][12  6][12  8][12 12][13  1][13 13][14  3][14 11]]`

And I have a numpy array that contains `result = [7 7]` How do I check if the result exists in the doubles?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

simply use `.tolist()`,

```
if result in doubles.tolist():
    print ("exists")
```

Comment: accorrding to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14766194/testing-whether-a-numpy-array-contains-a-given-row) your answer is incorrect

Comment: yes, just now checked. It's wrong. Thanks for correcting. I have edited it now.