# Does element exist in numpy array?

Tags: numpy, numpy-ndarray

numpy NOOB.

How best to see if an element exists in a numpy array?

Example:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([[1, 2], [2, 3], [3, 4]])
[2, 4] in a
# This evaluates to True because there's 
# a 2 (somewhere) and a 4 (somewhere)
# but I want to match [2, 4] ONLY. So...
[2, 4] in a  # Would like this to be False
[2, 3] in a  # Would like this to be True
[3, 2] in a  # This too should be false (wrong order [3, 2] != [2, 3])
```

I've looked at `np.where()` and that doesn't seem to be what I'm looking for. I get a similar result to the above using `np.isin([2, 4], a)`.

Don't need the index (though if it comes along for the ride that OK), just a boolean will suffice.

Comment: Agreed. I think it is a duplicate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was flagged as duplicate of [testing whether a Numpy array contains a given row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14766194) wherein [Tom10](https://stackoverflow.com/users/102302) provides the answer I sought:

```
np.equal([2, 3], a).all(axis=1).any()
```

Comment: When someone suggests a duplicate that you agree with, you should vote to close/flag as duplicate, or just accept the duplicate suggestion. You definitely shouldn't answer the question. If you have a solution that's not covered on the target, you can add an answer there.

Answer (score 1):

You're searching for 2 and 4 in a, try:

```py
[[2, 4]] in a
```

Comment: ...but that evaulates to `True`.

Comment: I've added clarification. See edited question. If [2, 3] in array, do not want to match with [3, 2] (order important). Only want to match if elements and order agree. THANKS