# Check if row contained in CSR matrix

Tags: python, sparse-matrix

I have a set of datapoints in CSR matrix format, and a list of clustered points from the dataset each in CSR matrix format. I have to go through my set of datapoints and figure out which cluster it is in. I have around 8000 datapoints total.

I tried looping through the datapoints and clusters and using the `in` keyword:

```
       for c in cluster:
           if datapoint.toarray() in c.toarray():
               # do stuff
```

But the `in` test returns true no matter what. Anyone have a more efficient method then checking element by element?

Note: dataset and cluster are CSR matrices. `toarray()` is a csr matrix method from the scipy library.

Comment: It might be useful to include an example of what `cluster` and `datapoint` look like. Also, how does the function toarray() work? If you give more details it will be easier to obtain a relevant answer

Comment: cluster and datapoint are csr_matrix objects. toarray() is a method belonging to the scipy.sparse_matrix class. I am not so familiar with working with sparse matrices, unfortunately, hence my difficulty

Comment: Great, you should edit the question and add this information, and also, include some example data in the question, so you that the burden is not upon those who answer. As a pointer, you can check this [link]( https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14766194/testing-whether-a-numpy-array-contains-a-given-row) , which gives some ideas on how to check whether an array contains a given row.

Comment: That link is actually where I got the in keyword from, but for some reason it is always passing when I use it on my sparse matrices. I will update the post with the information I mentioned shortly.

Comment: With the `toarray()` use, you are no longer testing sparse matrices, but just numpy arrays.  Construct a couple of sample arrays/lists, and get that step working.   You might as well do `datapoint.toarray()` once before the loop.