# How do you Check if each Row of a Numpy Array is Contained in a Secondary Array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, vectorization

My question is similar to [testing whether a Numpy array contains a given row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14766194/testing-whether-a-numpy-array-contains-a-given-row) but instead I need a non-trivial extension to the method offered in the linked question; the linked question is asking how to check if each row in an array is the same as a **single other row**. The point of this question is to do that for **numerous rows**, one does not obviously follow from the other.

Say I have an array:

```
array = np.array([[1, 2, 4], [3, 5, 1], [5, 5, 1], [1, 2, 1]])
```

I want to know if each row of this array is in a secondary array given by:

```
check_array = np.array([[1, 2, 4], [1, 2, 1]])
```

Ideally this would look something like this:

```
is_in_check = array in check_array
```

Where is_in_check looks like this:

```
is_in_check = np.array([True, False, False, True])
```

I realise for very small arrays it would be easier to use a list comprehension or something similar, but the process has to be performant with arrays on the order of 10<sup>6</sup> rows.

I have seen that for checking for a single row the correct method is:

```
is_in_check_single = any((array[:]==[1, 2, 1]).all(1))
```

But ideally I'd like to generalise this over multiple rows so that the process is vectorized.

In practice, I would expect to see the following dimensions for each array:

```
array.shape = (1000000, 3)
check_array.shape = (5, 3)
```

Comment: Can you provide dimensions you expect to see in practice? e.g. `array.shape`, `check_array.shape`. It would also help to know the number of unique values that can appear in the arrays (e.g. `1, 2, 3, 4, 5 -> 5` in this example.

Comment: Apologies, I think I made that confusing by using "indexes" instead of "rows" when describing how long it might be. I've fixed that, and given the expected shapes at the bottom. The algorithm is a symmetry finding algorithm based on distance, so I would imagine that there would only be 50-100 unique rows in 1,000,000 row array.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Broadcasting is an option:

```
import numpy as np

array = np.array([[1, 2, 4], [3, 5, 1], [5, 5, 1], [1, 2, 1]])

check_array = np.array([[1, 2, 4], [1, 2, 1]])
```

```
is_in_check = (check_array[:, None] == array).all(axis=2).any(axis=0)
```

Produces:

```
[ True False False  True]
```

---

Broadcasting the other way:

```
is_in_check = (check_array == array[:, None]).all(axis=2).any(axis=1)
```

Also Produces

```
[ True False False  True]
```