# numpy.all strange behaviour

Tags: python, numpy, mask

In the following code, I try to generate a mask on an image. The mask should only be true where the image (originalFormat, ndarry with shape [720, 1280, 3]) has a specific value (segmentId, nd array with shape [3,]).

Here's a small part of the code as minimal example:

```
originalFormat = np.array(Image.open(path_to_image))[..., :3]
segment_ids = np.unique(originalFormat.reshape(-1, originalFormat.shape[2]), axis=0)
segment_ids.sort(axis=0)

segmentId = segment_ids[0]
mask = originalFormat == segmentId
test = [True, True, True] in mask
mask = mask.all(axis=2)
test = True in mask
```

In the second line of the second block, I create the mask and get an output of shape [720, 1280, 3]. 
In the third line, I test if the image contains the segmentId.
In the fourth line, I apply np.all on the second axis of the mask to get a mask of shape [720, 1280].
In the fifth line, I test again, but now there are no true values in the mask.
So np.all returns false for all values, but should be true for at least one value.

[image]

Comment: `mask = originalFormat == segmentId` This will make `mask` a true/false value.  But then the next line does `... in mask`, which should be an error, because a single true/false value is not iterable.  As shown, this code cannot run.  Please show the real code.

Comment: can you simplify this example? would `mask = np.array([[[True, True, True]]])` work in the same way?

Comment: Well, this is the real code. mask is a numpy array with shape (720, 1280, 3) and segmentId is also a numpy array with shape (3,). And the resulting mask has also shape (720, 1280, 3)

Comment: @JohnGordon presumably those are np arrays, for which the return value of the `==` operator is not a single boolean value, but another np array

Comment: @Marco but can you simplify? take a (2,2,3) and and (3,), write down the actual values, and allow us to see exactly what happens? (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: When I only use ```mask = np.array([[[True, True, True]]])``` it works

Comment: indeed. now you need to find what happens that it stops working

Comment: With `originalFormat = np.arange(12).reshape((2, 2, 3))` and 
`segmentId = np.array([6, 7, 8])` the code works fine, exactly as expected.

Comment: notice: `[True, True, True] in np.array([[[False, True, True]]])` is actually `True`

Comment: @njzk2 Yes, that is the strange behaviour I meant ^^ It should work, but for some reason it doesn't. 
When i test for a specific value like ```[1, 111, 127] in originalFormat``` i get True, and there is also [True, True, True] in the mask. But applying np.all on it removes this true value for some reason

Comment: How sure are you that `segmentId` is contained in the image? Maybe it`s a format or datatype or numerical issue. Are the values integer or float?

Comment: Please read [ask] and [mre] and show code that someone else can **copy and paste, without adding or changing anything**, to see the **exact problem, directly**. This means: include the relevant `import`s; include small, hard-coded examples of what `originalFormat` and `segmentId` might be beforehand in order to show the problem; and explain step by step what should happen with those values and what the result should be.

Comment: @Arne Pretty sure. When i execute ```test = segmentId in originalFormat``` I get True as result

Comment: If you don't know specifically what data needs to be in your inputs to cause the problem, then start with your existing data, and try taking slices of it, until you find small pieces that show the problem. This is a fundamental [debugging](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) skill which you are [expected](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) to try applying before asking a question.

Comment: @Marco If you can't post an example of an array which triggers this problem, can you at least post an example of an image which triggers this problem? Preferably with code to load the image as an array.

Comment: @NickODell Im using a self generated image, so I don't have a link to it. Where can I upload it? :)

Comment: Users with at least 10 rep can post images in their questions.

Comment: Your [mre] doesn't have any example data.

Comment: Okay, I added the minimal example :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [testing whether a Numpy array contains a given row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14766194/testing-whether-a-numpy-array-contains-a-given-row)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The test `[True, True, True] in mask` does not do what you think it does. Here `[True, True, True]` is a plain Python list, and `in` is a plain Python operator, nothing NumPy-specific, whereas `mask` is a NumPy array.

Thus, it is actually not quite clear what the test checks. See the [linked question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14766194/testing-whether-a-numpy-array-contains-a-given-row?noredirect=1&lq=1). In any case, there do not need to be three `True` values in the same row for this test to evaluate as `True`. Here`s a small example reproducing the behavior you observed:

```py
originalFormat = np.arange(12).reshape((2, 2, 3))
segmentId = np.array([6, 4, 5])
```

Comment: ` whether three consecutive values are True` doesn't seem to be the case, though

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found the mistake.
It seems like the sort function also sorts the values in every single segmentId, so the resulting segment_ids do not occur in the image.

But this does not explain why

```
test = segmentId in originalFormat
```

is True, although segmentId is not in the image.

Comment: `segmentId in originalFormat` is `True` because that is equivalent to `(originalFormat == segmentId).any()`. Since `originalFormat == segmentId` is bound to contain one `True`, the expression evaluates to `True`

Comment: Instead, you need to do `(originalFormat == segmentId).all(axis=-1).any()` to check if any of the pixels in `originalFormat` have the value given by `segmentId`

Comment: PS. Your second snippet: `mask = mask.all(axis=2); test = True in mask` does basically what I said in "instead you need to do..."